# How to sort incidence matrix by the number of ones in two dimensions?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms, sorting

I have a set of "machines", each "machine" is described by a set of "tags". Not all tags present in all machines.

How to find largest subset of tags and largest subset of machines, where each tag is present in each machine?

I drew an incidence matrix like this:

[image]

now I want to sort its rows and cols to maximize area of "black" elements, something like this

[image]

(it is not guaranteed that the picture is well done)

How to do this?

---

I am trying to implement maximal [biclique enumeration algorith from the paper](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-110) and getting bicliques like this

[image]

Is it maximal in the sense? I.e. it is impossible to add one node and remain biclique?

Or it is erroneous output?

---

Code is here: https://github.com/dims12/iMBEA

Comment: This problem (if I've understood it correctly) is equivalent to finding the maximum biclique of a bipartite graph.  After some searching, I found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069365/finding-maximal-bicliques) that you may find useful.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We can improve on Bron-Kerbosch considerably for cliques if we don't have to list all maximal cliques as in that post, and probably the same thing can be done for bicliques.